# Robocopy website deployment script log file name truncated in AM

Tags: scripting, deployment, batch-file, time, robocopy

This is an IIS website deployment script I started to write.  It moves files from directory A to directory B and creates a log file with the date/time as the file name.  When it's run in the AM hours, the time part of the log file name gets truncated because of the spaces.  How can I fix this so it works for all times during the day (ie: 00.00.01, 00.00.11, 00.01.11, 00.11.11, 01.11.11 and 11.11.11 to give you some examples)?  If you like "9"s then use 9s.  Truncation occurs when we have 0s in the file name.. I think it treats it as a space.  It's been a few months since I looked at this, but more critical projects came up and I put this aside.  We just schedule the deployments in the evening for now.  Haha!  Essentially I want to use the least amount of IF statements as possible--but if you have a ton, I don't really care.  If you have anything in your arsenal, awesome!  :-)  The script uses a "." (not a ":") for the time delimiters since colons aren't allowed in file names.  If you're stumped, just say "MacGruber!" and take a drink of your diet Pepsi.

**Prerequisites:**
- You need to have the UI.Web folder created already
- You need the Robocopy.exe file in the path it expects
- You need a "logs" folder made before running script

```
REM **************************************************************
REM * TITLE:   LIMS Deployment Script                            *
REM * AUTHOR:  MacGyver                                          *
REM * PURPOSE: Deployment Script for IIS Web Server Files        *
REM *          - include all files recursively                   *
REM *          - excluded folders: .svn/obj                      *
REM *          - excluded files:   *.config, *.vb, *.cs, *.resx, *
REM *            *.vbproj, *.user, *.suo, AND others             *
REM * ASSUMES: UI.Web folder already exists                      *
REM **************************************************************

SET ROBOCOPY=".\robocopy.exe"
SET SOURCEDIR="\\tsclient\C\Source\websitename\UI.Web"
SET TARGETDIR="D:\web\docs\UI.Web"

SET DYYYY=%date:~-4,4%
SET DMM=%date:~-10,2%
SET DDD=%date:~-7,2%

SET THH=%time:~0,2%
SET TMM=%time:~3,2%
SET TSS=%time:~6,2%

REM - copy from one folder to another - the time doesn't work if you deploy the code in the AM, we need to fix that
%ROBOCOPY% %TARGETDIR% %TARGETDIR%_%DYYYY%-%DMM%-%DDD%_%THH%.%TMM%.%TSS% /S

REM - modify original folder with deployment changes & log the changes to a *.log file
%ROBOCOPY% %SOURCEDIR% %TARGETDIR% *.* /S /NP /XO /XD .svn obj /XF *.config *.vb *.cs *.resx *.vbproj *.user *.resources *.user *.suo > .\logs\Deployed_%DYYYY%-%DMM%-%DDD%_%THH%.%TMM%.%TSS%.log

iisreset
```

Comment: oh, and the target folder gets the date_time stamp in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to read your question a few times to understand it. I think you need to swap out the just your setting of the THH variable. Change:

```
SET THH=%time:~0,2%
```

to

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=: " %%a IN ('TIME /t') DO SET THH=%%a
```

If it cuts out the full two digits for the minutes, you can swap out your TMM for

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=: " %%a IN ('TIME /t') DO SET TMM=%%b
```

Comment: Been meaning to test both of these answers for the past few weeks, but our server that I deploy to is 1 hour ahead.. whenever I think of testing it early in the morning, it's 10am Ohio time (I'm in Wisconsin), so it's always too late.  I'm not a morning person.  Haha!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with variable substitutions, by changing...

```
SET THH=%time:~0,2%
```

...to...

```
SET THH=%time:~0,2%
SET THH=%THH: =0%
```

The second line replaces all spaces in `%THH%` with 0s.

See `SET /?` for more details.

Comment: Been meaning to test both of these answers for the past few weeks, but our server that I deploy to is 1 hour ahead.. whenever I think of testing it early in the morning, it's 10am Ohio time (I'm in Wisconsin), so it's always too late.  I'm not a morning person.  Haha!